# ¿Por qué esta comprobación es verdadera?

Tags: c++

tengo la siguiente comprobación:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    if (a && !b || a && !c){
        cout <<"hola";
    }else{
        cout <<"adios";
    }
}
```

Me dice que es verdadero. En mi entendimiento es falso; explico:
Un numero int sin declarar es falso de por sí, según he comprobado, por lo que falso y verdadero seria "falso" y falso y verdadero seria también "falso" por lo que tengo "falso || falso". Como puede dar de resultado verdadero?

Agradeceria que alguien me lo explicase gracias.

Comment: No sé mucho de C++, pero por lo que he leído ahora mismo en google, cuando no inicializas una variable definida como `int a`, es posible que tenga un valor por defecto diferente al que te imaginas cuando trabajas con ella. En este caso, si lo primero que haces es imprimir `a`, verás que vale 0. Pero si lo primero que haces es la comparación `a && !b`, es posible que tenga el valor 32765, que sería `true` en este caso. [Aqui](https://onlinegdb.com/r10cvNkWd) tienes un ejemplo para verificarlo. Si no me equivoco, esto se debe a que puede estar leyendo lo que había en la dirección de memoria

Comment: De todas maneras, con las pruebas que he hecho puedo decirte que el comportamiento de una variable local sin inicializar (`int a` por ejemplo) es muy ... inestable. De hecho, [en otras preguntas de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value) dicen que jamás se debe usar una variable local ***sin*** inicializar.

Comment: Gracias por los enlaces, me han servido para informarme más. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Un numero int sin declarar es falso de por sí

Tu afirmación sí que es falsa.

**Verdadero y falso**

Por un lado tenemos que en C++, se entiende como *falso* **única y exclusivamente** el valor 0, siendo el resto de valores equivalentes a *verdadero*.

**Variables no inicializadas**

Por otro lado, una variable no inicializada se queda con el valor que tuviese la memoria que ocupa la variable. Es decir en algún momento anterior, tu propio programa u otro cualquiera ha dejado ahí un valor, resultado de una operación que vete tu a saber de qué se trataría... pues bien, ese es el valor con el que inicializas tu variable.

Los tipos nativos, a diferencia de las clases, carecen de constructor, por lo que en ningún caso esperes que una variable entera se inicialice en 0 porque las probabilidades son 1/(2^32)... es más seguro jugar a la ruleta rusa.

**Ubicación de las variables**

Por conveniencia del compilador, las variables suelen declararse, siempre que sea posible, en los registros del procesador. De esta forma el compilador evita copias innecesarias para operar con dichas variables. Si el compilador decide que los registros no son una opción, podrá tirar también de la pila del programa, que para eso está.

En tu caso solo tienes 3 variables, un procesador 8086, de hace la tira de años, ya tenía 4 registros, con lo que es de suponer que las 3 variables *entran* en registros del sistema

**Estado de los registros**

Hay registros que son *reseteados* en momentos determinados (eso lo decide el compilador en el momento de generar el código binario que da lugar al programa). Esto se suele hacer para ofrecer un entorno de trabajo limpio ante determinadas situaciones (llamada a una función, por ejemplo).

Pero, por defecto, podemos asumir que los registros no se resetean.

Es decir, si tu variable tiene la suerte de aterrizar en uno de estos registros recién reseteado ... tu variable obtendrá un bonito valor cero. En caso contrario... vete tu a saber.

**Mezclamos todo en la batidora**

El resultado final dependerá, como ves, de muchas variables que no controlas (estado de los registros, el compilador, opciones de compilación). A esto se le llama comportamiento indefinido.

De hecho, si analizamos el ensamblador que genera [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/dTWEh1) compilando con -O3, vemos que es el siguiente:

```
.LC1:
    .string "adios"
main:
    sub     rsp, 8
    mov     edx, 5
    mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 8
    ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
    sub     rsp, 8
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
    call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
    mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
    mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZStL8__ioinit
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
    add     rsp, 8
    jmp     __cxa_atexit
```

Es decir, el compilador asume que el condicional va a resultar **siempre** falso y, en consecuencia, únicamente compila la opción `false`. Por eso no existe el texto `"hola"`.

Si ahora hacemos la misma prueba con [CLANG](https://godbolt.org/z/zv7MGo) ...

```
main:                                   # @main
    push    rax
    mov     edi, offset std::cout
    mov     esi, offset .L.str
    mov     edx, 4
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
    xor     eax, eax
    pop     rcx
    ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_example.cpp:             # @_GLOBAL__sub_I_example.cpp
    push    rax
    mov     edi, offset std::__ioinit
    call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
    mov     edi, offset std::ios_base::Init::~Init() [complete object destructor]
    mov     esi, offset std::__ioinit
    mov     edx, offset __dso_handle
    pop     rax
    jmp     __cxa_atexit                    # TAILCALL
.L.str:
    .asciz  "hola"
```

Vaya, CLANG asume que la condición va a ser **siempre verdadera**.

La triste relidad es que estás forzando un comportamiento indefinido. Bajo unas condiciones obtendrás un resultado y, bajo otras diferentes, otro diferente. No puedes fiarte ni de uno ni de otro.

Es como tirar a los dados para decidir si debes cruzar la calle o no... a veces acertarás, pero yo prefiero mirar a ambos lados.

Comment: Muy bien explicado, duda resulta. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

> Un numero int sin declarar es falso de por sí

Un `int` sin declarar no existe. Tú te refieres a un `int` sin inicializar.

---

Un `int` sin inicializar lo más probable es que sea verdadero. Esto es así porque en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (y en [c](/questions/tagged/c)) los números se pueden convertir implícitamente a valores booleanos, siendo cero `false` y `true` cualquier valor que no sea cero.

Cuando dejas una variable sin inicializar, ésta tiene un valor indeterminado (generalmente, valores resiudales de la memoria). En el caso de un entero de 32 bits tienes cuatro mil doscientos noventa y cuatro millones novecientos sesenta y siete mil doscientos noventa y cinco valores que no son cero (`true`) y uno que es cero (`false`) por lo que es bastante probable que "*Un número `int` sin **inicializar** sea verdadero*".

Pero "*bastante probable*" no significa que sea `true` siempre, así que se pueden dar combinaciones de valores de `a`, `b` y `c` que den lugar a que la expresión `a && !b || a && !c` sea verdadera. Lo que si es probable es que el programa te de resultados diferentes en diferentes ejecuciones pues leer el valor de una variable sin inicializar es un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido).